# HR margin issue in IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox

Please see below HTML code,

```
<html>
<body>
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                abc
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-size:0px">
                <hr />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                def
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

In firefox it shows like,

[image]

And in IE-8, it looks like,

[image]

So, it's amazing that padding doesn't remove for IE. !!!

If any one can help to resolve the same.

I checked solution in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165519/hr-margin-issue-with-ie6-ie8-ff). but any one can give any other solution.

Comment: why don't you just give a cell a border instead?

Comment: IE may not be happy with your HTML page in general as you don't have a doctype specified and you don't have a HEAD tag, TITLE tag etc. Also you'd need to include a css reset file in order to clear styles on everything such as the table and the HR etc.

Comment: Great !!! @BillyMoat you are right... There was something cause of <!DOCTYPE html>. I added it and it resolved issue.

Comment: Cool, I'll add that as an answer.

Comment: @scrappedcola you are right I can add border too. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE may not be happy with your HTML page in general as you don't have a doctype specified and you don't have a HEAD tag, TITLE tag etc.

Also you'd need to include a css reset file in order to clear styles on everything such as the table and the HR etc.

Tradtional doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

HTML5 doctype:

```
<!doctype html>
```